# Platforms in a class not moving when called in

Tags: java, class, variables, processing

For a university course I'm making a game with a friend. The general idea is that we have some platforms moving from right to left and each time one goes offscreen it is generated at a random `x` and `y` position on the right (within some limits). There will be a little sprite that jumps from platform to platform.

We have reached a problem we're not sure how to solve. We have all the right code and everything but the platforms just won't move. They should move to the left at a constant speed of `-4` pixels per frame (`rectVelocity`).

We cannot get them to move, though; they are static on the screen at the position each one is initially called in at.

This is the code as condensed as I can make it:

```
Platforms [] mainPlats;

void setup() {
  size(750, 400);

  mainPlats = new Platforms[3];
}

void draw() {
  level();
}

void level() {

  //This is the code for the first platform
  mainPlats[0] = new Platforms(200, 200, 100, 15); //These values need to be     set inside the class so that
  //they aren't constantly overwriting the movement variables in the class
  mainPlats[0].displayPlat();
  mainPlats[0].platTransition();


  //This is the code for the second platform
  mainPlats[1] = new Platforms(420, 300, 100, 15);
  mainPlats[1].displayPlat();
  mainPlats[1].platTransition();


  //This is the code for the third platform
  mainPlats[2] = new Platforms(570, 350, 100, 15);
  mainPlats[2].displayPlat();
  mainPlats[2].platTransition();
}

class Platforms {
  PImage platform;
  int rectX, rectY, rectWidth, rectHeight;
  int rectVelocity = 4;

  Platforms(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
    rectX = x; 
    rectY = y;
    // rectX = (int(random(600, 800))); //Tried to randomise start position,     failed hilariously
    //rectY = (int(random(150, 350)));
    rectWidth = w;
    rectHeight = h;
  }

  void displayPlat() {
    platform = loadImage ("images/tiles.png");
    //imageMode(CENTER);

    image(platform, rectX, rectY, 100, 15); //rectangle platforms replaced     with images
  }

  void platMove() {
    rectX -= rectVelocity;
  }

  void platTransition() {
    if (rectX < -200) {
      rectX = (int(random(700, 1000)));
      rectY = (int(random(150, 350)));
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: @jonrsharpe The language is Processing, hence the [tag:processing] tag. C Timothy: Can you post your sketch as an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of this disconnected class?

Comment: @jonrsharpe No worries. Processing was a pretty terrible choice for a language name!

Comment: I've posted it as an MCVE, hope that helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the draw() function, you call your level() function, which **initializes** your Platform array every single frame.

This means that you create **new** Platforms at their starting positions **every frame**. You never see the platforms move, because as soon as you do move them, you replace them with new platforms at the starting positions again.

So step one is to move their initialization out of the level() function and only call them once, at the beginning of your sketch- the setup() function would be one place you could put them.

Your other problem is that you never actually call the platMove() function. So step two is to make sure you call that function.

A solution might look something like this:

```
Platforms [] mainPlats;

void setup() {
  size(750, 400);

  mainPlats = new Platforms[3];
  mainPlats[0] = new Platforms(200, 200, 100, 15);
  mainPlats[1] = new Platforms(420, 300, 100, 15);
  mainPlats[2] = new Platforms(570, 350, 100, 15);
}

void draw() {
  level();
}


void level() {
  mainPlats[0].displayPlat();
  mainPlats[0].platMove();
  mainPlats[0].platTransition();

  mainPlats[1].displayPlat();
  mainPlats[1].platMove();
  mainPlats[1].platTransition();

  mainPlats[2].displayPlat();
  mainPlats[2].platMove();
  mainPlats[2].platTransition();
}
```

Also note that you shouldn't load the image every single frame, either. You should only load it once, at startup. You also might want to use a for loop to iterate over your Platforms instead of referring to every single index. But these don't really affect your problem.

Answer (score -1):

You've got rectX as positive values (>0) when you construct the platforms, but you are checking for `rectX < -200` when you call `platTransition`, which is why it never does anything.

Comment: This isn't the case. The platMove() function decreases the rectX value, so they should eventually go negative. The problem is that he's re-initializing the values every frame, and he's never actually calling the platMove() function.

Comment: @KevinWorkman, I was going off of the code given, which I assumed was incomplete.  Yes, indeed, platMove is never called, but platTransition() is, right after construction, so I'm assuming OP wanted platTransition to do something right after construction, which it cannot.